# Why are groups of type $F_2$ finitely presented?

Tags: group-theory, fundamental-groups, covering-spaces, group-presentation, cw-complexes

There are some equivalent definitions for "finiteness properties", but let's define that $G$ is a *group of type $F_n$* if it is the fundamental group of a CW complex $X$ whose $n$-skeleton is finite and whose universal cover is contractible.

A claim that I see everywhere but without a proof is that a group is $F_1$ if and only if it's finitely generated, and a group is $F_2$ if and only if it's finitely presented.

Actually both directions (of both claims) are not clear to me (although the specific implication I need is the one in the title...).

In one direction I guess I should use the presentation complex but the universal cover need not be contractible. In the other direction I know that examining the $2$-skeleton of a complex is enough to determine the fundamental group of the whole complex, but does the fact that this skeleton is finite imply immediately that the fundamental group is f.p.? Or should I use contractibility of the universal cover somehow?

I'll be thankful even for a reference to a proof, I don't know why I can't find any... Is it so elementary? :)

Comment: This is an intuitive result. Roughly: the fundamental group’s relators are given by the 2-cell structure of your complex, and if there are only finitely many 2-cells, it follows that there are only finitely many relators.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the proof the claim that $G$ is of type $F_2$ if and only if it is finitely presented. The proof of $F_1$ if and only if finitely generated should be straightforward after seeing this one.

Let $G$ be of type $F_2$. We will use the following fact (this is in chapter 1 of Hatcher).

**Fact.** If $X$ is a topological space and $Y$ is the result of gluing a $2$-cell to $X$ via the attaching map $\varphi \colon D \rightarrow X$ (where $D$ is a $2$-disk), then $\pi_1(Y) \cong \pi_1(X) / \langle\!\langle \gamma \rangle\!\rangle$, where $\gamma$ is an element of $\pi_1(X)$ in the conjugacy class of $\varphi(\partial D \cong S^1)$.

This is proved by applying the Seifert-van Kampen Theorem to the decomposition $Y = A \cup B$, where $A = X \cup \varphi(D \smallsetminus \{x\})$ and $B = \varphi (U)$, where $x$ is a point in the interior of $D$ and $U$ is a small neighbourhood of $x$ in the interior of $D$.

Since $G$ is of type $F_2$, then $G = \pi_1(X)$ where $X$ is a CW complex with $X^{(2)}$ is finite (the fact that the universal cover is contractible is not important for this direction). As you remarked, $G = \pi_1(X^{(2)})$, so we will assume that $X = X^{(2)}$. Since $X^{(1)}$ is a finite $1$-complex, $\pi_1(X^{(1)})$ is a finitely generated free group (this is done in Hatcher, for example); we label the generators of $\pi_1(X^{(1)})$ by $a_1, \dots, a_n$. Label the (finitely many) attaching maps of the $2$-cells by $\varphi_\alpha \colon D \rightarrow X^{(1)}$, where $D$ is a copy of the $2$-disk. Let $\gamma_\alpha$ be an element of $\pi_1(X^{(1)})$ in the conjugacy class determined by the loop $\varphi_\alpha(\partial D)$. By iteratively using the fact, we obtain that $\pi_1(X) = \langle a_1, \dots, a_n \rangle / \langle\!\langle \gamma_{\alpha_1}, \dots, \gamma_{\alpha_m} \rangle\!\rangle$, where $m$ is the total number of $2$-cells. Writing the $\gamma_{\alpha_i}$ as words $r_i$ in the generators $a_j$, we obtain a finite presentation $\langle a_1, \dots, a_n \mid r_1, \dots, r_m\rangle$ for the fundamental group.

Now we prove the converse. Suppose that $G$ is finitely presented. As you pointed out, $G$ is the fundamental group of a finite $2$-complex (usually called its presentation complex), but its universal cover $\widetilde X$ may not be contractible. Note that the property that $\widetilde X$ is contractible is equivalent to $\pi_n(X) = 0$ for all $n \geqslant 2$ (see Hatcher's section on $K(G,1)$ spaces). If $\pi_2(X) \neq 0$ in our case, then we can glue in $3$-cells, to obtain a $3$-complex $X_3$ containing $X$ such that $\pi_2(X_3) = 0$ as follows. Each generator of $\pi_2(X)$ is represented by a $2$-sphere $S_\alpha \subseteq X$; we glue a $3$-ball $B_\alpha$ to $X$ with attaching map identifying $\partial B_\alpha$ to $S_\alpha$, this makes $S_\alpha$ trivial in $\pi_2$ and does not affect $\pi_1$. After doing this process for each generator we obtain the desired spaces $X_3$ (note that there is no guarantee that $X_3$ has the finitely many $3$-cells). It is possible that $\pi_3(X_3) \neq 0$. If this happens, we glue in $4$-cells to obtain $X_4 \supseteq X_3$. The space $X_\infty = \bigcup_{n \geqslant 3} X_n$ has $\pi_1(X_\infty) = G$, has finite $2$-skeleton, and all of its higher homotopy groups vanish, hence its universal cover is contractible.